# Use Docker.io without the build-in NAT function but with DHCP

Tags: nat, dhcp, docker

I am unable to use the NAT networking of docker in my setup.
Instead i wan't to use DHCP configured IPs or allow docker to dynamically choose an IP from a preconfigured range.

Is this possible?
I think NAT is a very bad idea und should not be used in production.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible today, but is planned for the 1.0 release via a plugin.

Comment: So i guess the only chance is to use NAT with a firewall rule on the host.